# How to use createAsyncThunk with Typescript? How to set types for the `pending` and `rejected` payloads?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

Right now I've got these actions that I use for an upload thunk's lifecycle.

```
type UPLOAD_START   = PayloadAction<void>
type UPLOAD_SUCCESS = PayloadAction<{ src: string, sizeKb: number }> 
type UPLOAD_FAILURE = PayloadAction<{ error: string }>
```

And I'd like to convert it to a `createAsyncThunk` call, assuming it will reduce the code. But will it?

From the example on https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk it should be something like:

```
const uploadThumbnail = createAsyncThunk(
  'mySlice/uploadThumbnail',
  async (file: File, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await uploadAPI.upload(file) as API_RESPONSE
    return response.data   // IS THIS THE payload FOR THE fulfilled ACTION ?
  }
)
```

This is how I would handle the life cycle actions?

```
const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'mySlice',
  initialState: // SOME INITIAL STATE,
  reducers: {
    // standard reducer logic, with auto-generated action types per reducer
  },
  extraReducers: {
    // Add reducers for additional action types here, and handle loading state as needed
    [uploadThumbnail.pending]: (state,action) => {
       // HANDLE MY UPLOAD_START ACTION
    },
    [uploadThumbnail.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      // HANDLE MY UPLOAD_SUCCESS ACTION
    },
    [uploadThumbnail.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      // HANDLE MY UPLOAD_FAILURE ACTION
    },
  }
})
```

**QUESTION**

I'm assuming the return of the `createAsyncThunk` async handler is the `payload` for the `fulfilled` action, is that right?

But how can I set the `payload` types for the `pending` and the `rejected` actions? Should I add a `try-catch` block to the `createAsyncThunk` handler?

Is this the correlation I should be doing?

- `pending === "UPLOAD_START"`
- `fulfilled === "UPLOAD_SUCCESS"`
- `rejected === "UPLOAD_FAILURE"`

**Obs:** From the pattern I'm imagining, it doesn't look I'll be writing any less code than what I'm already doing with three separate actions and handling them in my regular reducers (instead of doing it on the `extraReducers` prop). What is the point of using the `createAsyncThunk` in this case?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Most of your questions will be answered by looking at one of the TypeScript examples a little further down in the docs page you linked:

```
export const updateUser = createAsyncThunk<
  User,
  { id: string } & Partial<User>,
  {
    rejectValue: ValidationErrors
  }
>('users/update', async (userData, { rejectWithValue }) => {
  try {
    const { id, ...fields } = userData
    const response = await userAPI.updateById<UpdateUserResponse>(id, fields)
    return response.data.user
  } catch (err) {
    let error: AxiosError<ValidationErrors> = err // cast the error for access
    if (!error.response) {
      throw err
    }
    // We got validation errors, let's return those so we can reference in our component and set form errors
    return rejectWithValue(error.response.data)
  }
})


const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    // The `builder` callback form is used here because it provides correctly typed reducers from the action creators
    builder.addCase(updateUser.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.entities[payload.id] = payload
    })
    builder.addCase(updateUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
      if (action.payload) {
        // Being that we passed in ValidationErrors to rejectType in `createAsyncThunk`, the payload will be available here.
        state.error = action.payload.errorMessage
      } else {
        state.error = action.error.message
      }
    })
  },
})
```

So, observations from there:

- when using TypeScript, you should use the `builder` style notation for extraReducers and all your Types will be automatically inferred for you. You should not need to type anything down in `extraReducers` by hand - ever.
- the `return`ed value of your thunk will be the `payload` of the "fulfilled" action
- if you `return rejectWithResult(value)`, that will become the `payload` of the "rejected" action
- if you just `throw`, that will become the `error` of the "rejected" action.

Additional answers:

- "pending" is your "UPLOAD_START". It does not have a payload and you cannot set it.
  All three of "pending"/"rejected"/"fulfilled" will have `action.meta.arg` though, which is the original value you passed into the thunk call.
- in the end, this is probably a little less code than you would write from hand, and it will be very consistent throughout your application. Also, it catches some bugs that would go unseen otherwise.
  Do you know that

```js
  const manualThunk = async (arg) => {
    dispatch(pendingAction())
    try {
      const result = await foo(arg)
      dispatch(successAction(result))
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(errorAction(e))
    }
  }
```

actually contains a bug?
If `successAction` triggers a rerender (which it most likely does) and somewhere during that rerender, an error is `throw`n, that error will be caught in this `try..catch` block and another `errorAction` will be dispatched. So you will have a thunk with both the success and error case true at the same time. Awkward. This can be circumvented by storing the result in a scoped-up variable  and dispatching outside of the try-catch-block, but who does that in reality? ;)
It's these little things that `createAsyncThunk` takes care of for you that make it worth it in my eyes.

Comment: im dispatching multiple asyncThunks in ThunkAction and i need to parse through rejected results before dispatching next one. is there a way to properly type those? is it a bad practice overall?

Comment: @vilemcech You might need to cast the type of your `dispatch` to `AppDispatch`, then it should be typed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach, using the [SerializedError](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-errors) type

in src/store/reducer/api.ts

```
... code

export const getFunction = createAsyncThunk("slice/type", async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/url");
    if (res.data) {
      const data = res.data as unknown as {
        someJSON: Type[];
      };
      return data;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    const {
      response: { data, status },
    } = e as unknown as {
      response: { data: string; status: number };
    };
    throw {
      name: "Request Failed",
      message: data,
      code: `${status}`,
    };
  }
}); 

...code
```

in a slice add corresponding action for the rejected case

/store/reducer/reducer.ts

```
export const Slice = createSlice({
name: "slice",
  initialState: {message:"", type:""},
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getFunction.rejected, (state, action) => {
      const { code } = action.error;
      state.type = parseInt(code ?? "", 10) === 500 ? "error" : "warning";
      state.message = "Failed to get response from server";
    });
  },
});
```