# How to use createAsyncThunk with Typescript ? How to set type for the fulfilledAction meta?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I would like to return some metadata (currentPage, ...) throught the second argument in fulfillWithValue(value, meta) as showing in the [redux-toolkit doc](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator).
However Typescript says that I can pass only one argument (the value to be returned).

```js
const findBooks = createAsyncThunk(
    "books/findBooks",
    async (filterQuery: string, thunkAPI) => {
        // simplified search logic that return books and currentPage index
        const { books, page } = await fetchBooks(filterQuery);
        
        // Expected 1 argument, but got 2. ts(2554)
        return thunkAPI.fulfillWithValue(books, { page }); 
    }
);
```

Here is an example slice

```js
const usersSlice = createSlice({
    name: "mySlice",
    initialState: {}, // SOME INITIAL STATE,
    reducers: {
        // standard reducer logic
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(findBooks.pending, (state, action) => {
                // HANDLE MY SEARCH_START ACTION
            })
            .addCase(findBooks.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                 // HANDLE METADATA
                state.search.currentPage = action.meta.page;
                // HANDLE MY SEARCH_SUCCESS ACTION
            })
            .addCase(findBooks.rejected, (state, action) => {
                // HANDLE MY SEARCH_FAILURE ACTION
            });
    },
});
```

How can I solve this TS error ?

*(sorry for bad writing, I am a French speaker)*

## Expectation

I want typescript to recognize the second argument of `thunkAPI.fulfillWithValue(value, meta)`;

## Proposal

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67227015/how-to-use-createasyncthunk-with-typescript-how-to-set-types-for-the-pending), it is poosible to set the type of payload but not for the meta.

May be I can create a extended type of ThunkAPI, but I think is not a good idea

```js
interface MetaThunkAPI extends BaseThunkAPI<any, any> {
    fulfillWithValue: <T = any, S = any>(value: T, meta: S) => T;
}
```

Comment: The code you have transpiles and runs correctly, but I also see that Typescript issue. What is the point in returning `page` in the action's meta data versus just returning it in the payload?

Comment: @DrewReese , normally, I would like to have the same structure with other reducers which don't have metadata, but return a value

Comment: You *are* returning a value either way though, and one way is pretty straight forward.

Comment: @DrewReese ,You are right, I will just use the payload to return all values. Thank you